# Function to convert a number to a word in r programming

Tags: r

I have a data set where in the months are given as 1,2,3,..12
So I want to convert them to words like 1-January, 2-February ,3-March so please help me with this.

Comment: Check out `month.abb` and `month.name`

Answer (score 2):

```
> data <- c(12, 1, 4, 3, 4, 9, 10)
> month.name[data]
[1] "December"  "January"   "April"     "March"     "April"     "September" "October"
```

It isn't clear if you want the number of the month in the result, but if you do you can use `paste`:

```
> paste(data, month.name[data], sep = '-')
[1] "12-December" "1-January"   "4-April"     "3-March"     "4-April"     "9-September" "10-October"
```

Answer (score -1):

First some reproducible data (always useful)

```
dat <- data.frame("X1" = sample(1:12, 20, replace = T))
```

I'd then create a function to do what you ask (pasting the numbers and names):

```
conv <- function(df, x){
    paste0(as.numeric(df[,x]), "-", month.name[as.numeric(df[,x])])
    }
```

Then the successful implementation:

```
dat$X2 <- conv(dat, "X1")
```

And the output

```
    > dat
       X1          X2
    1  12 12-December
    2   7      7-July
    3   9 9-September
    4   1   1-January
    5  12 12-December
    6   5       5-May
    7   3     3-March
    8   4     4-April
    9  12 12-December
    10  8    8-August
    11 11 11-November
    12  9 9-September
    13  1   1-January
    14  9 9-September
    15  6      6-June
    16  9 9-September
    17  4     4-April
    18  9 9-September
    19 10  10-October
    20  3     3-March
```